# Is there a Chrome extension or native keyboard shortcut to search Chrome window names?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

Chrome has made strides in productivity features such as tab grouping, tab search and window naming. It's changed my workflows and I was able to let go of various half-baked extensions I had used previously, especially for tab search.

What's missing now is searching and switching to named windows by keyboard shortcut, without having to use the "Window" menu on Mac or cycle through ALT+Tab on Microsoft Windows.

I've not found a native Chrome keyboard shortcut for this, nor have I found an extension that does this simple thing. Does a solution exist?

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but there's a simple function to get that list, `chrome.windows.getAll()`. Might be worth requesting from a popular extension like tab session manager if they haven't added already

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thanks for the tip. Maybe I'll try to code up my own extension.